# find $f′(z)$ and determine where $f(z)$ is analytic, and when it is entire.

Tags: complex-analysis

Equation: $f(z) = e^{\sin(z^{5})}$

My assumption here is that by the chain rule, that because I know $z, \sin(z), e^z$ are all entire, I can apply that to $z^5, \sin z^5, e^{\sin(z^{5})}$ are entire by the chain rule.

Simply putting that $f'(x)=5z^4*
\cos(z^5)*e^{\sin(z^{5})}$

Are my assumptions correct for this?

Comment: There's a theorem that tells you that the composition of analytic functions is analytic (the same goes for entire). The proof of this is essentially the chain rule, as you've cited.

Comment: The composition of power series (with compatible domain and image) works well because $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$ is analytic for $|z| < r$ iff it converges absolutely there. The chain rule is useful more for [holomorphic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analyticity_of_holomorphic_functions).